# Cannot convert all hex values to binary

Tags: java, integer

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(input);
int a = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2), 16);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
```

Above mentioned code that takes in hex value and convert it into binary. However, this would not work on input "`0xBE400000`" but it works fine for "`0x41C20000`"

Comment: ok. is this a statement, or is there a question coming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BE400000` is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (whose hex representation is `7FFFFFFF`).

Therefore you'll need to parse it with

```
long a = Long.parseLong(input.substring(2), 16);
```

Comment: and if `Long` isn't big enough, go to `BigInteger`/`BigDecimal`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)

`long l = Long.parseLong(input.substring(2), 16);`

but if your value is greater than 2^63 - 1 you may use use a `BigInteger`'s constructor:

> BigInteger(String val, int radix)
>   Translates the String representation of a BigInteger in the specified radix into a BigInteger.

`BigInteger b = new BigInteger(input.substring(2), 16);`

Answer (score 3):

Since `0xBE400000` is in the range of an unsigned int you can use: [`parseUnsignedInt(String s, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-)

```
int a = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(input.substring(2), 16);
```

With `parseUnsignedInt(input, 16)` you can parse values from `0x00000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF`, where:

- 0x00000000 = 0
- 0x7FFFFFFF = 2147483647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE)
- 0x80000000 = -2147483648 (Integer.MIN_VALUE)
- 0xFFFFFFFF = -1
- 0xBE400000 = -1103101952